# Build a recursive tree at compile time

Tags: macros, rust

I created a recursive tree in rust, but it is not fast enough for what i need (https://github.com/Noxivs/tree).

So I would like to build it at compile time but I'm not good enough to understand syntax extension with "recurcive matchers".

Could you give me a way to do it ?

EDIT 1 : I can probably do a thing like that to build a simple match in a macro expander

```
let d = vec!(
        (0, "match 0"),
        (1, "match 1"),
        (3, "match 3"),
);


fn  ms(m: Mather_) -> Matcher {
    Spanned {
        node: m.clone(),
        span: DUMMY_SP
    }
}

let lhs_nm =  gensym_ident("lhs");
let rhs_nm =  gensym_ident("rhs");

let  m = d.iter().map(|&(ref i, ref s)| {
    vec!(
        ms(MatchSeq(vec!(
            ms(MatchNonterminal()), // no args
            ms(MatchTok(FAT_ARROW)),
            ms(MatchNonterminal()), // no args
        ))),
        ms(MatchSeq(vec!(ms(MatchTok(COMMA)) // no args
        )))
    )
}).collect();
```

Comment: @ZachSpencer I'm not asking to do it. I'm asking to give me a way to do it as you can see (like point me a link or something like that).
I'm a beginner and I assume. There is not yet a large doc about syntax extensions, and it's a bit difficult.

However i read some examples on github and this [article](http://blog.burntsushi.net/rust-regex-syntax-extensions) 
but I still have no idea how to do nested matchers.

Comment: You should have a look at https://github.com/sfackler/rust-phf. It uses a rustc parser plugin and a lib to create a hashtable at compile time.